# WSL Virtual Hard Disk not reclaiming space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have an Ubuntu install (I believe it's 18.04) on WSL. I have the virtual disk stored in its own partition with 100GB of space. The virtual disk is "Dynamic" with a maximum size of 250GB. I was using a machine learning library that stores "spilled objects" from RAM onto the filesystem. It completely filled the 100GB of space on the partition, so it only has 6MB left. I cannot get into my Ubuntu install anymore.

I installed a separate install of Ubuntu and mounted the virtual disk and deleted the "spilled objects" that were clogging my filesystem. This did not resolve the issue and I still can't boot into Ubuntu. The virtual disk only has 30GB of actual space again.

I attempted to use `Optimize-VHD` to reclaim space but none of the provided modes worked.

I attempted to use `DISKPART` to compact the virtual disk, which gave me only ~20MB of space and allowed me to boot into my Ubuntu install. I expected the space to be reclaimed when I finally got in, but it did not. I tried to logout and `wsl --shutdown` and boot again, but it still did not reclaim the space. I thought I had fixed it, but now I'm back to square 1 with 6MB of space and unable to get into the OS.

I attempted to use `DISKPART` to shrink the virtual disk, but I could not because it's dynamic.

The only solution I currently see is to manually create a new virtual disk in place of the current one with a properly set maximum size and copy all the data from the old one to the new one.

Is there another solution besides this? Why is the unused space not automatically being reclaimed? Why will the OS not boot when it actually has ~70GB of free space available to it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  How much free space do you have on the host/Windows drive?  Is it possible that things aren't working because there's no space left there?  If that's the case, then you may have to clean up something *else* on the drive in order to get enough space for the `Optimize-VHD` to even work.

Comment: Also would be interested in any error messages or behavior you saw from the `Optimize-VHD`.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my original post; the host drive has 5.88MB of space left, with the virtual disk taking up the rest. `Optimize-VHD` does not output any messages. When I run the command, it reaches 20%, jumps to 30%, and then stops. I don't know if its stopping because of an error or if it's completed.

Comment: Ah, no apologies necessary - You were clear; I just misread that detail!

Comment: Event Viewer shows "The system successfully compacted 'W:\Ubuntu\ext4.vhdx'." I do, however, see previous entries that state, "Failed to compact the virtual disk.", but the latest one was successful.

Comment: In order for Optimize-VHD to work you need to have enough room on the disk that contains the file. "Why will the OS not boot when it actually has ~70GB of free space available to it?"  - Without logs that is difficult to determine.

Comment: @runedog48 *"but the latest one was successful"* - Oh, that sounds encouraging.  Are you saying that the problem is resolved?  Or is Ubuntu still unable to boot?

Comment: I have fixed it. I manually created a new VHD with a 95GB maximum, copied the filesystem over and replaced the old VHD with the new one. If you want to answer the title ( the space is not being reclaimed because there's not enough space to perform the operation ) I'll mark this as answered. Thanks for the help.